# Passing so far entered data to controller

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

In a form I have different fields (name, age, ...) and the possibility to upload an image. This I want to realize on a different view. The problem is that the data, that is made so far, are not passed to the controller when I want to change the controller. Here a small example of my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)

        <img src="@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Image" class="imagePreview" />
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Upload a pic from you!", "UploadImage", new { model = Model }, null)
            @* This is the 'problematic' action *@
        </li>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here the method that is calling the upload controller:

```
public ActionResult UploadImage(Person model)
{
    // properties in the passed model are not set
    return RedirectToAction("UploadImage", "UploadImage");
}
```

How it is possible to get the entered information without using the submit button?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? You're saying that you want to use a different controller to do the photo upload, but you also want to pass the data (name, address etc.) that's on the form to the separate upload controller?

Comment: Yes thats correct. I want to keep the transient data while uploading the pic. After saving the photo I want to go back to the calling page and fill the data that the user has entered so far.

Comment: Rico, sounds like you want to perform an Asynchronous upload of the picture before submitting the form. If that correct?

Comment: I agree with Dave A. I think the HTML.ActionLink is always going to make synchronous call to the separate controller which will take you away from the form. So you need to that bit async via something like a jQuery AJAX call so that you can preserve the form data and submit it to the first controller when the photo upload completes.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this blog post](http://goo.gl/hcLD58) by Bryan Sampica on asynchronus file uploads with MVC.  We just used it for a smooth async file upload experience so we didn't have to leave the page.  This solves your problem of how to persist the transient data.  If your users are using a modern browser (IE 10+, Chrome, FF, etc...) the progress bars actually show file upload progress.  It's fairly easy to setup, but, if you follow the instructions to the letter, does require that you add a webAPI controller to your project.